# Select records that match 2 values in a column

Tags: sql

I have a table (TEST) with 3 columns:
APP_ID, USER_ID, ACCESS_CD

I need a query to find the user_id's that have two different values in the first column.

here is data example:

| app_id | user_id | access_cd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3456 | 6 |
| 3 | 2344 | 7 |
| 1 | 2334 | 8 |
| 1 | 1111 | 6 |
| 3 | 3456 | 4 |

etc......

for my database, APP_ID only has two values (1 or 3) how would I be able to find all rows in this case only user_id's that for example have both app_id 1 and 3 in the data. In this example my query would return user_id: 3456.

Comment: tag your database as well

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
select user_id
from tablename
group by user_id
having count(distinct app_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be useful as well:

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM TEST
WHERE USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM TEST WHERE APP_ID = 1)
AND USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM TEST WHERE APP_ID = 3);
```